# how to stop looping in file in c#?

Tags: c#

I'm Trying to save a customer in file but when i'm saving it, it keeps looping the person i entered i do not know where i'm doing it wrong  .The problem is i'm thinking my logic is good but i know i'm doing something wrong somewhere which i can not find it .If you could help me i really appreciate it.

```
public partial class admin : Window
{
    accounts acclist = new accounts();
    customers cuslist = new customers();

    public admin(string pin, accounts myacc, customers mycus)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        acclist = myacc;
        cuslist = mycus;
    }

    public void saveaccount()
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("account.txt"))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < acclist.Count; i++)
            {
                var info = new List<string>
                {
                    acclist[i].accounttype.ToString(),
                    acclist[i].PIN,
                    acclist[i].accountnumber,
                    acclist[i].accountbalance.ToString()
                };
                var account = String.Join(";", info);
                writer.WriteLine(account);
            }
        }
    }


    //save to customer file
    public void savefile()
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("customer.txt"))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < cuslist.Count; i++)
            {
                var info = new List<string>
                {
                    cuslist[i].NAME.ToString(),
                    cuslist[i].pin,

                };
                var customer = String.Join(";", info);
                writer.WriteLine(customer);
            }
        }
    }

    // add user 
    private void Sub_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        customer newCus = new customer();
        account newAcc= new account();
        try
        {
            newCus.NAME = Nameadd.Text;
            newCus.pin = pinadd.Text;

            newAcc.PIN = pinadd.Text;
            newAcc.accountnumber = Accountnumadd.Text;
            newAcc.accounttype = 'C';
            for (int i = 0; i < acclist.Count; i++)
            {
                {
                    if(newAcc.accounttype == 'C')
                    {
                        newAcc.PIN = pinadd.Text;
                        newAcc.accountnumber = Accountnumadd.Text;
                        newAcc.accounttype = 'S';
                    }
                }
                cuslist.add(newCus);
                acclist.add(newAcc);
                savefile();
                saveaccount();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes bro its not that

Answer (score 0):

Consider the use of a `foreach` loop. This loop is best used for applications like the one in your `savefile()` method. It's great for applications where you want to perform an action for every item in a list or collection.

See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

EDIT: The requested example:

```
        List<string> FruitBasket = new List<string>();
        FruitBasket.Add("apple");
        FruitBasket.Add("banana");
        FruitBasket.Add("orange");
        foreach (string fruit in FruitBasket)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(fruit);
        }
```

and this results in an output of:
`apple`, `banana`, `orange`.

In the foreach loop you need to declare a variable of the same type as your collection (so in this example I had a List of strings so I made my variable a string, and then they keyword `in` assigns this variable to each item in that collection, one at a time, starting from the beginning.

Comment: i really do not know how to use foreach loop can you help me a bit with it plz

Comment: @MassodAli Sure I'll post an example and explain it but you should check the example at the bottom of the link I shared. It'll always be more accurate and helpful than anything I can ever produce. But I hope my example makes sense. *see my edit in my answer

Answer (score 0):

In your "save" event, your doing a for loop over the "count" of elements in your account list.  That account list variable is global in scope to your class.  The problem is that in your loop, you're adding to that list... so really the list you're iterating over is mutating right under-neath you.  As you add that customer, the loop starts next iteration, checks the "count", and ends only when "i" is equal in value to the count.  However each pass you're adding to the count... so technically you'll never reach the end as the accList.Count is constantly increasing by 1 each pass.

```
private void Sub_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    customer newCus = new customer();
    account newAcc= new account();

    try
    {
        newCus.NAME = Nameadd.Text;
        newCus.pin = pinadd.Text;

        newAcc.PIN = pinadd.Text;
        newAcc.accountnumber = Accountnumadd.Text;
        newAcc.accounttype = 'C';
        for (int i = 0; i < acclist.Count; i++) // here you are checking acclist.Count... each iteration this increases by 1, thus i will never technically ever be equivalent to acclist.Count
        {
            {
                if(newAcc.accounttype == 'C')
                {
                    newAcc.PIN = pinadd.Text;
                    newAcc.accountnumber = Accountnumadd.Text;
                    newAcc.accounttype = 'S';
                }
            }
            cuslist.add(newCus);
            acclist.add(newAcc); // <-- this is where you're adding to acclist each time.  However inside this loop you're constantly increasing its size... thus your infinite loop you're hitting.
            savefile();
            saveaccount();
        }
        }
        catch(Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
        }
    }
```

I suggest for one, you use a ForEach statement as it's been suggested.  Also, use a separate list to hold your "new" accounts.  If you need to add to acclist for whatever reason, then after you've added to your new list, iterate over that and add each one of those back to your acclist.  This way you avoid mutating the very object you're looping over.

Another way is to first store the "count" into a variable and check against that so it never changes.

```
var myCounter = acclist.Count
for (int i = 0; i < myCounter ; i++) 
        {
...
```

But, I don't know which option is best for you as I obviously don't know the larger context of what it is you need to ultimately do. :)  Either solution should stop your infinite loop though.

Comment: Thank you for taking ur time to answer my question  .where should i add te foreach

Comment: using a "foreach" over a "for" won' necessarily fix your problem... but it could lead to performance improvements.  Plus some developers view it as easier to read... others don't.  So it's up to you.  If you want to use a foreach, replace your "for" loop with with the "foreach" syntax.  See this article:  https://www.dotnetperls.com/for-foreach